# What are the core wire and wrap wire guages for a set of .11-.52 electric guitar strings?

Tags: electric-guitar

I'm looking into hand wrapping guitar strings and I am having trouble finding information regarding the gauges of the core wires and wrap wires. I'm a DIYer and I don't like buying strings when I know it's possible to wind them.

Answer (score 1):

If you're becoming a serious diyer, then you need to furnish yourself with a caliper gauge or micrometer, which will reveal information like this. Such a useful tool - I use one to determine the existing gauge of strings on guitars I may be working on.